# Python: use a string as a variable?

Tags: python, string, variables

I want to write a python script that creates several dictionaries at once then print the dictionaries out but I don't know how to convert a string to a variable.

```
number = 0

while (number < 10):
    number = number + 1
    dictionarynumber = ("D"+str(number)) # creates the dictionarys name(D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10)
    var(dictionarynumber) = {"Fruit":"Apple","Book":"Oliver Twist","Building":"White House"} #Of course var() doesn't work but I placed it here to get my point across
    print(dictionarynumber)
```

---

After Answers:

I liked the idea about dictionaries and taking out the unneeded "D" makes sense. What do you guys think of this?

```
dict = {}
n = 0

while (n < 10):
    n = n + 1
    d = n
    d = {"Key":"Information"}
    dict[n] = d

print(dict)


# Output = 
#          {1: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           2: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           3: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           4: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           5: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           6: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           7: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           8: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           9: {'Key': 'Information'},
#           10: {'Key': 'Information'}}
```

Comment: Use a list (leave off the "D" in the indexer) or another dictionary. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Or use a dictionary-of-dictionaries -- a computed key is still better than a computer name -- if you want to be able to name them arbitrarily rather than just with sequential numbers.

Comment: Your `number` loop should instead be: `for number in range(1, 11):`

Comment: Yes, you can go crazy with dictionaries. (`{1: {'a': {'i': 1, 'ii': 2), 'b': 3}, 2: 4, 3: {'knight': 'ni', 'parrot': None}}` Just don't try to use a dictionary as a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to give each dictionary a name, put them in a dictionary.

```
dicts = {}
# dict_list = []
for i in xrange(10):
    dictionary_key = ('d{0}'.format(i))
    dict_item = {"Fruit":"Apple","Book":"Oliver Twist","Building":"White House"}
    dicts[dictionary_key] = dict_item
    # dict_list.append(dict_item)
```

If you're not hung up on using a name for your dictionaries, put them in a list.

Comment: A blank dictionary, I didn't know you could do that. Seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to create a mixed data type but I'm unclear on what kinda structure you want so I'll give you a 2 answers and hope one is right.

1st, If you are trying to create a bunch of dictionaries and print it you would do it like this:

```
diclist = [{"Fruit":"Apple"},{"Book":"Oliver Twist"},{"Building":"White House"}]
print(diclist[1])
```

2nd, going by the example you have given you might be aiming to create a dictionary of lists. For example

```
listDic = {'Fruit':['Apples', 'Bannanas', 'Durian'], 'Book':['Oliver Twist','Flashman', 'Catch 22']}
print (listDic)
```

and you can access it like this:

```
print(listDic['Fruit'])
```

would result in

> ['Apples', 'Bannanas', 'Durian']

and this
    print(listDic['Fruit'][1])
would result in

> Bannanas

If I missed the answer you wanted or you want more detail just drop a comment.